# Get Rows and Columns of an embedded table within another table via HTML Agility Pack

Tags: html, vb.net, html-table, nodes, html-agility-pack

VB.2012 using the HTML Agility Pack.
I spent several hours trying to figure this out and it was my ignorance on the format of the inputs. That being the case here is my input: a simple HTML table with two other tables embedded

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="plan">
                <tr>
                    <td class="textBold" valign="bottom">XX&nbsp;<u>999</u></td>
                    <td class="centerText" valign="bottom">X1</td>
                    <td class="centerText" valign="bottom">X2</td>
                    <td class="centerText" valign="bottom">X3</td>
                    <td class="centerText" valign="bottom">X4</td>
                    <td class="centerText" valign="bottom">X5</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal" valign="bottom">TOTAL</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="Text">PRIMARY</td>
                    <td class="centerText">4</td>
                    <td class="centerText">8</td>
                    <td class="centerText">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerText">1</td>
                    <td class="centerText">3</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="TextColor">SECONDARY</td>
                    <td class="centerTextColor">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerTextColor">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerTextColor">2</td>
                    <td class="centerTextColor">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="centerTextColor">2</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="TextTotal">TOTAL</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">4</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">8</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">2</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">1</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">5</td>
                    <td class="centerTextTotal">20</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="75%" class="" textcolorvalign="bottom">Number of fuelings:0</td>
                    <td width="25%" class="" textcolorvalign="bottom" align="right">Meals:2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am only concerned with the data that's in the inner table "plan".

```
        Dim html As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        html.OptionOutputAsXml = False
        html.LoadHtml(htmlTable)

        Dim docNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = html.DocumentNode

        'parse the plan table if it exists
        If docNode IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim hTable As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = docNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='plan']")
            If hTable IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each hRow As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In hTable.SelectNodes("//table[@class='plan']//tr") '"//tr"
                    Debug.Print("   InnerText=>[{0}] InnerHtml=>[{1}]", hRow.InnerText, hRow.InnerHtml)

                    For Each hCol As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In hRow.SelectNodes("//table[@class='plan']//tr//td") '"//td"
                        Debug.Print("      InnerText=>[{0}] InnerHtml=>[{1}]", hCol.InnerText, hCol.InnerHtml)
                    Next hCol
                Next hRow
            End If
        End If
```

To the right I have the strings that I was using initially //tr and //td. My logic was that since I was using the nodes hTable and hRow that I would get the corresponding subnodes. However it seems this will get me ALL rows and ALL columns from ALL tables. After testing it seems I have to fully qualify each loop with //table[@class='plan']//tr and //table[@class='plan']//tr//td. Why is that??? It just doesn't make sense to me since I am explicitly using the subnode objects hTable and hRow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256122(v=vs.110).aspx), in XPath `//` means to search from the root, and if you want to search from the current context you would need `.//` instead.  So, try `.//tr` and `.//td` for searches relative to the current element.

Comment: Cant believe it was that simple. I thought i read the xpath formats but I was too quick on the draw. I understand now but still when you say // on a subnode wouldn't it make sense to get root from that object and not the whole thing? Anyways thanks.